# Avalability of SNOPT optimization solver

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, reference-request, nonlinear-programming, discrete-optimization

I'd like to know if SNOPT solver is available free of cost for academic research in any of the optimization software packages.

I came across a few softwares that have SNOPT, but those require a commercial license.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that SNOPT [requires a paid license](http://www.sbsi-sol-optimize.com/asp/sol_product_snopt.htm), even for single-use by an academic. According to the linked-to website, SNOPT would cost you a single payment of $416.

Have you considered using free, open-source software? For example, you could try using [IPOPT](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt).